# Cannot import Popper.js in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli, popper.js

I was following [this tutorial](https://codesandbox.io/s/basepopover-component-no-animation-ypim2?file=/src/components/BasePopover.vue) in order to learn how to make popovers in my VueJS app.
When I compiled the projects I got an error that says:

`[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: _popperjs_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is undefined"`

[image: import error]

I traced the problem to the `BasePopover.vue` component - first `<script>` line that says `import Popper from "popper.js";`
In my application I changed that to `import Popper from "@popperjs/core";` but the error still keeps appearing.

So I followed the official [Popper.js tutorial](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/tutorial/) to simplify things.
I installed via `npm i @popperjs/core` (also tried using `VueCLI` as seen in the image below and via `npm install @popperjs/core --save`).
[image: vue cli install]

This is my current code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button id="button" aria-describedby="tooltip">My button</button>
    <div id="tooltip" role="tooltip">My tooltip</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
//import Popper from "@popperjs/core/lib/popper";
import Popper from "@popperjs/core";
export default {
  name: "TestView",
  components: {
  },

  data() {
    
      const button = document.querySelector('#button');
      const tooltip = document.querySelector('#tooltip');

      Popper.createPopper(button, tooltip);
    
    return {
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  padding: 350px 0;
  background-color: #C4DFD1;
}
</style>
```

I don't know what else to do. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do this

```
import { createPopper } from '@popperjs/core';
```

and not as you have above i.e

```
import Popper from "@popperjs/core";
```

see here: [module bundlers](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/#module-bundlers)

Comment: Thank you kindly! It seems there's no `Popper` in this new version (the tutorial mentioned in the beginning seems to use an outdated one, where it DOES exist).
Unfortunately even with a copy/pasted code from the "module bundlers" code block, now I get an error saying `Popper: Invalid reference or popper argument provided. They must be either a DOM element or virtual element.` - which makes no sense but that's a separate question.

Comment: you have to have an element where you are applying popper, make sure where there is a query selector in your js code, there is a DOM element you are referring to e.g a button using its class or id. In vuejs, make sure you have an existing component referenced by popper

Comment: Thank you. I was using the proper `Id`s, because the official tutorial is using them (which is why it didn't make sense to me), but I modified the way my Popper instance was being created using the component `refs` and a couple of other things and made it work somehow. :D

Answer (score 6):

```
import { createPopper } from '@popperjs/core';

export default {
name: "TestView",
components: {
},
data() {
return {
};
},
mounted(){
  const button = document.querySelector('#button');
  const tooltip = document.querySelector('#tooltip');
  createPopper(button, tooltip);
}
};
```

Instead of ids you should use refs(I have not used them here to avoid confusing you), which will ensure that there is no clash, since you app can have multiple elements with the same Id, eg #button. When using UI library like popper js, always try and put their code in the mounted hook, the mounted hook ensures that the elements you are targeting eg #button are in the dom

Comment: Thank you. I was using the `Ids` and it wasn't working. I managed to figure out to use the `refs` instead in the `createPopper` and a couple of other things and made it work somehow. The topic problem was just me not importing it properly, though.
Also, thank you for the tip for the `mounted hook`! I'm still kind of new to VueJS, so it's really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You must add `this.$nextTick` for the code that will run only after the entire view has been rendered (https://vuecomponent.com/integrations/popperjs.html)

```
import { createPopper } from '@popperjs/core';
      
export default {
  name: "TestView",
  components: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
    };
  },
  mounted(){
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      const button = document.querySelector('#button');
      const tooltip = document.querySelector('#tooltip');
      createPopper(button, tooltip);
    });
  }
};
```